# Apache loads mod_ssl but <IfModule mod_ssl.c> ignored in my vhosts

Tags: apache, https, httpd.conf, vhosts, mod-ssl

I'm trying to secure my server's vhosts. I installed LE/Certbot fine, and had no issues. I installed/upgraded any dependencies to get certbot to work, again they ran fine.

`mod_ssl` is installed and loaded. I ran `phpinfo()`, and in the `LoadedModules` section, I see `mod_ssl`.

However, in my vhosts file, when I use

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost *:443>
        ... 
    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

That specific site `<VirtualHost></VirtualHost>` block is ignored (i.e. I can't access site defined in VirtualHost block) UNLESS I remove/comment out the ` wrapper.

httpd version:

```
$ httpd -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)
Server built:   Apr 12 2017 21:03:28
```

I can't find much online, so I'm a little stuck. I'm worried there's something more sinister that's going to catch me out if I don't figure out why.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Cheers

Comment: Try removing the `.c`, leaving `<IfModule mod_ssl>`. If that doesn't work, screw `IfModule` and just take it out of the wrapper.

Comment: Hey,  I appreciate the reply! I removed the `.c` and restarted apache, and still not luck. Yeah, that's what I'm going to have to. I just hope it's nothing serious!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In case anyone else runs into this issue, it's because I was loading the vhosts configuration files before the mod_ssl extension.

I moved the `Include vhost` call to below the `Include conf.d/*.conf` call, in `httpd.conf` and restarted Apache and it worked.

Hope that helps someone!

Comment: Literally spent 4 days researching this. I also have `<IfModule mod_ssl.c>` wrapper and I ended up resolving by switching the order of the `IncludeOptional` statements at the end of the `http.conf` file. Thank you for posting back here with your solution.